# Сформировать массив B из положительных элементов массива A, имеющих четный индекс

Tags: java

Задача: Дан массив A вещественного типа, содержащий 20 положительных и отрицательных элементов. Сформировать массив B из положительных элементов массива A, имеющих четный индекс.

Есть половина кода, заполнение массива A.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayB {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int size = 20;
        int[] arrayA = new int[size];
        System.out.print( "Введите массив A: " );
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i=0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            arrayA[i] = a;
            System.out.println(arrayA[i] + " ");
        }
        int [] arrayB;​
```

дальше заполнение массива B:

```
        int [] arrayB = new int [j];
        for ( i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i=i+2){
        if ( arrayA[i]  > 0 ){
           arrayB [j] = arrayA[i];
           j++;
           System.out.println(arrayB[j]);
        } 
    }
}
```

но программа выполняет только заполнение A, а дальше пишет running...

Comment: А в чём трудность? Проходишь массив А от начала до конца, проверяешь чётная твоя i или нет и проверяешь отрицательный ли элемент. Если условия удовлетворяют, то записывай его в массив В.

Answer (score 1):

Если реализовывать через массивы, нужно проходить `arrayA` 2 раза:
1. Оцениваем длину `arrayB`;
2. Заносим необходимые элементы.
Можно сделать проще, если использовать `List<Integer>` или `Set<Integer>`. Для работы с такими структурами не нужно знать их размер поэтому получить необходимые числа можно за 1 проход. В тоже время, `ArrayList` - это, по сути, тот же массив.

Вот реализация без использования Java Collections API:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        int size = 20;
        int[] arrayA = new int[size];
        System.out.print( "Введите массив A: " );
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int bLength = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < arrayA.length; i++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            if(i % 2 == 0 && a > 0){ //при заполнении считаем длину массива
                bLength++;
            }
            arrayA[i] = a;
            System.out.print(arrayA[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");

        //заполняем выходной массив, длина которого уже известна
        int[] arrayB = new int[bLength];
        int j = 0; //индекс в выходном массиве
        for(int i=0; i<arrayA.length; i+=2){
            if(arrayA[i] > 0){
                arrayB[j] = arrayA[i];
                System.out.print(arrayB[j] + " ");
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```